# Difference between enter 0,0 and push ebp?

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm new to assembly and working through examples to get a better understanding. I came across 2 programs one which uses `enter 0,0` and other using `push ebp; mov ebp, esp`. I understand `pusha` pushes all general purpose registers onto the stack. I'm confused if these two terms can be user interchangeably or not?

```
enter 0,0
pusha
```

equal to

```
push ebp
mov ebp, esp
```

in assembly?

Comment: Read the instruction set reference about what the instructions do. No, they are not equivalent, the second code just matches the `enter 0,0` it does nothing to save registers except `ebp`.

Comment: [enter](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_78.html) , [pusha](http://x86.renejeschke.de/html/file_module_x86_id_270.html)

Answer (score 3):

The single instruction `enter 0, 0` is equivalent to the pair of instructions `push ebp` `mov ebp, esp`.  The `enter` requires 4 bytes to encode, the combo requires only 3 bytes.

Your 2 code snippets aren't equivalent because of the `pusha`.
Either remove it from the first, or add it to the second.